# Call each Play method in player object after call videojs getPlayers method

Tags: javascript, arrays, video.js

I have some players in my page:

```
<video id="cam-1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin tv-video"
                style="float: left">
                <source src="../videos/video11.webm" type="video/webm">
                <p class="vjs-no-js">
                    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
  <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                </p>
            </video>
```

and I'm getting all of them with videojs.getPlayers() method and then I'm doing:

```
for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this._players).length; i++) {
    this._players[i].play();
}
```

but this._players[i] is returning "undefined".

Even when I call just

```
videojs("cam-1").play() it doesn't work!
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating the keys in a wrong manner, do it like below,

```
var players = this._players;
players.forEach((itm) => {
  players[itm].play();
});
```

Or if you want me to give a solution in your own way then,

```
var keys = Object.keys(this._players);
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    this._players[keys[i]].play();
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work... but I think that there is still something wrong at my code... I tried to run videojs("cam-1").play() and it didn't work either, while it works at another sites... I added some html code... maybe it may help to find the mistake.

Comment: I found the other mistake! It was a css class... anyway, your tip helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about video.js but what you are doing is searching for property in this._players Object which does not exist. You are confusing this._players as an array where it is an object. What you need to do it 

    `for (var i in this._players) {
        this._players[i].play();
}`

Above i will be the key.

**for (var i  in ... )**   works for both Object and Array.